# C# цепочка функций

Tags: c#, функции, extension

Есть 2 метода расширения :

```
 static class MyClass
{
    public static string FirstExtension(this string a,int b)
    {
        return $"{a} is {b}";
    }
    public static string SecondExtension(this string a)
    {
        return $"And second is {a}";
    }
}
```

В теле функции main эти функции вызываются   так :

```
 string str = "Just Test";
 str.FirstExtension(10).SecondExtension();
```

В данном примере функция SecondExtension работает с результатом работы функции FirstExtension?

Comment: _В данном примере функция SecondExtension работает с результатом работы функции FirstExtension?_ - да

Comment: Да, но результат вы никуда не сохраняете и он будет утерян

Comment: `"And second is Just Test is 10"`